# How to provide demo account for Google Play Store if app uses only Google Sign-in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console

My application is rejected due to not providing demo account for Google Play Store.

If I want to provide demo account there is like login and password field I need to fill in. But my application only supports Google sign-in via Firebase. In my case, what should I do?

Comment: You can have [only one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ro.alexmamo.firebase) authentication mechanism. Where do you get the error message?

Comment: Play Store rejected my app that I have to provide demo account for them to open it. How did you provide demo account for [your app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ro.alexmamo.firebase)?

Comment: There is no demo account. And Google auth is enough to publish an app in Play Store.

Comment: If your app has authentication system and users can't access the content without authenticating, I think you have to provide Google with demo account which includes login and password. I always did it, but this is the first time that my app only uses Google sign-in as it only requires Google account. So I'm confused, how can I provide them with that as they are asking me and rejected my app due to it. But I saw your app that it has only Google Auth if I'm not mistaken. How did you got approved it by Google Play Store. I would really appreciate your help

Comment: I didn't do anything special. I have simply add it to Google Play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after completing several steps my application is approved:

1. Add content description to sign-in button in english. For example "Google sign-in button".
2. Automatically fire up Google sign-in dialog after opening the activity/fragment/composable.
3. Provide test Google account and instruction. You can do it by going: App Content -> App Access. Create test Google (Gmail) account. Don't add any kind of two-step authorization to your test google account.
4. If you are using Firebase Google Authentication, don't forget to add sha1 and sha256 keys from Google Play Developer Console. You can get it by going: Release -> Setup -> App integrity -> App signing.

And finally after doing these steps if it doesn't work, just write them email understanding the situation. You can write email if your app is rejected from them. You can get email address from Google Play Developer Console once your app gets rejected.